# Compare specific value to an value in a text file

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement

I have the following code to check if the specific value is not the same as in the text file I have on my server. In PHP it's quite simple: `$str = '1.3'; if($str != '1.2') { die('not the same!'); }` and in Java it's... well. I don't know really. It's because of that I'm asking you how it should be?

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("http://erik-edgren.nu/weather-right-now.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if(str != "1.2") {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ny version finns att hämta: v" + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    in.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "error 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object comparison in Java is done using the `equals` method, `==` compares references. So `if(str != "1.2")` should be `if(!str.equals("1.2"))`.

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer solved my problem. I'll accept it when I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `!str.equals("1.2");` and your problem is solved.